# pintrest like android scrollview with two list views

Tags: android, user-interface

### pintrest like android scrollview

Basically I am looking to have two list views which scroll only together (not separately) when I scroll the screen. (Like if they where in the same scroll view)
Each if the list items of course most remain clickable. Each if the items in each list can have different lengths, so no I can't have a single adapter.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Trick is ListView withing a ListView. You need to have a main listview and then a layout that holds other two listview. The subsequest scroll can be sync between those both using onScrollListener and sync between them. Its quite a project by itself but you could give a try.

Another way is to build a custom view which you want to display as pInterest, might take more than expected time.

Answer (score 1):

there are a lot of libraries for that, here are some of them
https://github.com/vladexologija/PinterestListView
https://github.com/chenyoca/pinterest-like-adapter-view